# Cannot route static files in ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: asp.net, routes, webforms

We have legacy code to maintain and, to solve a specific customer customization problem, we want to route calls to some files to other files. That is, when the app calls a particular ASPX, it will end up hitting another ASPX.

If you call:

```
www.foo.com/admin/admin.aspx
```

It will actually hit:

```
www.foo.com/customizations/customer1/admin/admin.aspx
```

This is not a good design but this is legacy code. We just want to solve this.

We are using the `System.Web.Routing` framework to solve it. This works fine when you set `RouteExistingFiles` to true, except for static files (CSS, JavaScript and Images). 
When I first tried it, it retrieved this error:

> There is no build provider register for the extension '.css'.

So I did register a build provider in the web.config file for the `.css` extension. I used this build provider: `PageBuilderProvider` because someone recommended it in the internet.

It works! But the CSS is being served with `text\html` content type.

**How do I achieve this?**

TL;DR: I want to use routes in ASP.NET Web Forms to make a call for a specific CSS file to actually retrieve another one. A customer needs this for customization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try coding a HttpHandler. I had to do something similar but for PDF files, I coded a custom HttpHandler in the end - works very well. You can even set the content type in the HttpHandler code and have a pattern matched path the handler will be used for in the web.config. You can also configure it in web.config not to execute if the path does not point to an existing file e.g. so a 404 is returned without having to code that in the handler itself. I can't post my code (VB.NET) ATM because I'm using a tablet but google search for tutorials. You will also probably need to use the TransmitFile function to actually write out the css file. Is it a web forms project or web site? If its a web site there is a special way of registering the HttpHandler in the web.config.

Comment: If you like I could post a link to the tutorial I followed.

Comment: Sorry for your response, but I'd really need the current URLs for static content to keep working. I just need to route them to different static files. An ASHX handler would require me to change URLS. Thank you anyway.

Comment: No when I did it the URL did not change, you don't need an ASHX you can create a class which inherits from IHttpHandler I think.